# Creating a non-rectangular raster in R

Tags: r, spatial, r-raster

In my analysis I have to loop over the cell id (i.e. cell numbers) of a raster, this is non-optional and done in a different software setting (BUGScode) which I am not to fluent in. My raster has to fit a shapefile (my study area) exactly, otherwise I would be looping over cell numbers I have no values for or interest in and then... well you know what happens then ;).

**reproducible example**

```
### get a shapefile
GER<-getData("GADM", country="DEU",level=1,download=T,path=getwd())

### make a raster
raster<-raster(ext=extent(GER), vals=0, crs=crs(GER))

plot(raster);plot(GER, add=T)

### now make the raster fit exactly to the German borders
mask.raster<-mask(raster, GER)

plot(mask.raster) ### looks right, but WAIT
plot(mask.raster, colNA="black") ### the border cells were only set to NA, which is problematic if your raster contains NA in the first place, i.e. if you used rasterize to count points in the raster cells

trim.raster<-trim(raster, values=NA)

plot(trim.raster, colNA="black"); plot(GER, add=T) ### trim only trims complete rows/columns from the raster

crop.raster<-crop(raster, GER)

plot(crop.raster, colNA="black");plot(GER, add=T) ### crop only crops to extent
```

How do I get my raster to exactly fit the outline of my study area and thus **not** be rectangular?

*This is done regularly in all kinds of GIS-software, but I am currently limited to R.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have recently found out, `raster` in R  implies some kind of projected matrix and thus can only be rectangular (or in special cases diagonal) but NEVER actually fit to shape.

As to what happens when you just simply mask the raster file.
If you loop over say `cell in 1:ncell(raster)` you may encounter following problems:

1. Longer processing time because you have to loop over potentially many more cells.
2. Error messages if you are combining sums etc.
3. In my case, an issue, where if you used `rasterize` to count some points in your raster and the count came up 0 (which is interpreted as NA... nothing to count) the same class of cells WITHIN your study area to be skipped. This can easily be avoided by setting the raster values that are "counted" as empty=NA to 0 and then masking the raster but it is a case for many many workaraounds...

Answer (score -1):

By most definitions, and the file formats that support them, rasters are rectangular. You assert that this is not the case *in all kinds of GIS-software*, but I do not think that is true, and you do not provide any evidence. Perhaps you are thinking of (raster-like) rectangular polygons?

Also, I have no idea about *what happens then*. Most competent R software would simply skip raster cells that are `NA`.

Comment: try rastering the same shapefile in QGIs and you will get raster cells only over the polygon ;)